# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space , while retrieving data by using Jdbctemplate : (RowCallbackHandlerResultSetExtractor.extractData)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeeDataByDate(Date dateCreated) throws Exception {
        List<Employee> listDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        
        sqlServTemplate.query(SyncQueryConstants.RETRIEVE_EMPLOYEE_RECORDS_BY_DATE, new Object[] { dateCreated },
                new RowCallbackHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                        Employee emp = new Employee();
                        emp.setEmployeeID(rs.getString("employeeID"));
                        emp.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
                        emp.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
                        emp.setMiddleName(rs.getString("middleName"));
                        emp.setNickName(rs.getString("nickName"));

                        byte[] res = rs.getBytes("employeeImage");
                        Blob blob = new SerialBlob(res);
                        emp.setEmployeeImage(blob);

                        
                        // .....
                        
                        listDetails.add(emp);
                    }
                    
        });
        
        return listDetails;
    }
```

Here I'm trying to retrieving records of the employee table.Because of BLOB data It's saying  **OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** . Could any one help me on this ?

It's a stand-alone application, I'm doing syncing from one table to another table. So unable to use pagination. Every day 2k record will sync at mid-night by cron job. Give some idea how I can solve this issue.

```
SELECT * FROM Employees with(nolock) WHERE cast (datediff (day, 0, dateCreated) as datetime) >= ?
```

This query giving me all data based on date, (around 2k record each day).
If I'm commenting

```
byte[] res = rs.getBytes("employeeImage");
                        Blob blob = new SerialBlob(res);
                        emp.setEmployeeImage(blob);
```

This line then no issue. Other wise It's throwing error.

Please give some idea, if possible give some sample code.
I'm struggling from 2days in this possition.

Comment: And what is the question? Too much data to fit into the available heap space.

Comment: Increase your heap or you can simple use pagination and get 100 record per query

Comment: I have another table which is having a 4lakh record, there is no issue.(I'm not using any pagination also) only in this table having the issue.

Comment: Only the difference I found is here for each record having 120 fields, there it's only 50 fields.

Comment: BLOB/CLOB fields? My guess: megabyte sized portrait photos. Test by not using all fields.

Comment: Yes, For each employee one BLOB (image) field is there.

Comment: Your guess is right, Could you please tell how I can resolve this issue. ?

Answer (score 1):

As some other commenters have mentioned you can either increase your heap space or limit the amount of records you are returning from your query and process them in smaller batches.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading an MB sized image in bytes, it will consume your HEAP memory..
instead try using BinaryStream:

```
InputStream image = rs.getBinaryStream("employeeImage");
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather then adding each user to the list you could process them one at a time.  Put each record in the other database as it's pulled from the source database, rather then adding them to the List which is causing the OOM error.  If there is some other processing downstream then inject a class into this DAO that handles the actual processing/writing to the target DB.